# How to truncate a file that is being written to

Tags: files, nohup

I have a long running process on a remote computer which I started like this:

```
$ nohup ./process > output &
```

My problem is that the output file is getting bigger and bigger fast. And of course, the only use this file has to me is monitoring the progress of the process:

```
$ tail -f ./output
```

So I would like to truncate the file from time to time to conserve the space (I'm afraid I might run out of space). So I tried this:

```
$ truncate -s 0 output
```

But it seems since the file is open and being written to, this command has no effect. As a test, once I removed the file but then there wasn't a new one created. So I had lost my progress report and I had to restart the process.

Is there any way I can truncate the file while it is being written to?

Comment: Is it necessary to write to a file? I mean, maybe it is enough to write to a terminal window directly (without redirection to the file `output`).

Comment: I'm writing to file since my SSH connection might drop and I need to be able to log back in and continue monitoring again. The solution depicted above has the benefit spawning a new process which is not a child process of connection. The process might take weeks to complete.

Comment: How many output lines do you want to keep?

Comment: Maybe you can use `logrotate`. See for example [this link](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-linux-log-files-with-logrotate/)

Comment: I only care about the few last lines each time look into the file

Answer (score 1):

While a full size solution may involve `logrotate`, it might work with a simpler solution according to the following demo example.

I started a process, #1, that writes the current date and time to the file `output`.

```
while true;do LC_TIME=en_US date>>output;sleep 10;done &
```

Then I started a process, #2, that copies `output`, and uses tail to truncate the redirected copy back to `output`. This keeps writing from process #1 alive. It might work in your case too.

```
while true;do cat output > ttt;tail ttt > output;cat output;echo '----------------------------';sleep 60;done &
```

Example of output from process #2,

```
Sun Nov 25 14:31:40 CET 2018
----------------------------
Sun Nov 25 14:31:10 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:31:20 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:31:30 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:31:40 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:31:50 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:32:00 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:32:10 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:32:20 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:32:30 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:32:40 CET 2018
----------------------------
Sun Nov 25 14:32:10 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:32:20 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:32:30 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:32:40 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:32:50 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:33:00 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:33:10 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:33:20 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:33:30 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 14:33:40 CET 2018
----------------------------
```

I also tested how to make a demo example that does not hangup, if the window/connection is closed,

```
nohup bash -c 'while true;do LC_TIME=en_US date>>output;sleep 10;done' &
```

and

```
nohup bash -c 'while true;do cat output > ttt;tail ttt > output;sleep 60;done' &
```

which can be monitored with `LANG=C tail -f ./output` from another window/connection,

```
Sun Nov 25 15:01:05 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:01:15 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:01:25 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:01:35 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:01:45 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:01:55 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:02:05 CET 2018
tail: ./output: file truncated
Sun Nov 25 15:00:35 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:00:45 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:00:55 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:01:05 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:01:15 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:01:25 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:01:35 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:01:45 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:01:55 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:02:05 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:02:15 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:02:25 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:02:35 CET 2018
Sun Nov 25 15:02:45 CET 2018
```